# D3 - event on chart type change

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

Is there any callback for the chart type change in d3

I know there is a `legendClick` event callback which is called when we click on legend but I want a callback when I click on Grouped/Stacked types

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use the listener of the radio button? `d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function(){ //convert chart and Do something over here });`

Comment: @Gilsha you cannot! **reason 1**. its not an input 
**reason2** if we attach our click listener then internal click function will not work that is graph will not change on click.

Comment: I thought it is an input element with type radio and as per my understanding  the chart type does not change on click. My bad.. Thanks Cyril :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it like this:

```
chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { 
    nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); 
});
```

Now when **grouped** is clicked it will log

New State: {**"stacked":false**,"disabled":[false,false,false]}

Now when **stacked** is clicked it will log

New State: {**"stacked":true**,"disabled":[false,false,false]}

Working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oRTegvQGzAYVf2Ujs5PO?p=preview)

Hope thsi helps!